# From which version on of Android Webview the core-js is not needed?

Tags: android, webview, polyfills, core-js

Our project is about 10 years old and heavily relied on various polyfill like core-js.

To reduce the bundle size and improve performance, we are going to say good by to legacy browsers and abandon core-js.

The future supported browser will be:

- Chrome 64+
- Edge 79+
- Firefox 67+
- Opera 51+
- Safari 12+

And we want to add Android Webview

Not sure from which version of **Android Webview** it is safe enough not to import core-js.

Appreciate if detailed explanation is followed.